# How to rearrange data in pandas dataframe according to specific criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to convert data in a pandas dataframe in a single column into a dataframe with multiple columns.

Original Dataframe Data:

| Date | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/14/2022 12:35:00 PM | TypeA | 1 |
| 10/14/2022 12:35:00 PM | TypeB | 2 |
| 10/14/2022 12:35:00 PM | TypeC | 4 |
| 10/15/2022 12:35:00 PM | TypeA | 6 |
| 10/15/2022 12:35:00 PM | TypeB | 17 |
| 10/15/2022 12:35:00 PM | TypeC | 4 |
| 10/16/2022 12:35:00 PM | TypeA | 3 |
| 10/16/2022 12:35:00 PM | TypeB | 1 |
| 10/16/2022 12:35:00 PM | TypeC | 12 |

Here is what the data needs to look like when rearranged:

| Date | TypeA | TypeB | TypeC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/14/2022 12:35:00 PM | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 10/15/2022 12:35:00 PM | 6 | 17 | 4 |
| 10/16/2022 12:35:00 PM | 3 | 1 | 12 |

Here is the code to create the original dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd                  
    
data = [['10/14/2022 12:35:00 PM', 'TypeA', 1],      ['10/14/2022 12:35:00 PM', 'TypeB', 2],     ['10/14/2022 12:35:00 PM', 'TypeC', 4],     ['10/15/2022 12:35:00 PM', 'TypeA', 6],     ['10/15/2022 12:35:00 PM', 'TypeB', 17],      ['10/15/2022 12:35:00 PM', 'TypeC', 4],     ['10/16/2022 12:35:00 PM', 'TypeA', 4],     ['10/16/2022 12:35:00 PM', 'TypeB', 1],     ['10/16/2022 12:35:00 PM', 'TypeC', 12]]                  
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['DateTime', 'Type', 'Value'])
```

How do I programmatically convert df to the desired arrangement?

Comment: It matters quite a bit whether your original `df` looks like the *table* you've supplied, or like the *code* you've supplied. For the first `df`, you can do: `df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Type', values='Value')`. For your second (code) `df` this won't work, because it has duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The table was correct and I edited the python code to match.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: Yep this is perfect. Thank you! I didn't know the term for what I was trying to do!

Comment: Thanks. So, that would be a basic use of `df.pivot`, which you can find in the suggested duplicate: `res = df.pivot(index='DateTime', columns='Type', values='Value').reset_index()`. Add `res.columns.name = None` to get rid of `columns.name`.